# “Il doit d’affronter”?

Tags: grammaire

I saw this while reading a wiki article:

> Le jeu débute sur un rêve de Corrin, dans lequel il doit d'affronter ses deux familles.

Why is it *d’affronter* and not just *affronter*? I can think of no reason for *de* to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Il doit d'affronter* is incorrect, that's either:

> Il doit affronter...

or

> Il se doit d'affronter...

The second form is stronger and literary.